# [Java][functional] Collect fields items from list into a list of such fields

Tags: java, list, functional-programming

I have:

- a class BoardField representing a field on a chessboard
- a class Chessman representing a chessman like Pawn, Knight, Queen etc.
- a List representing all chessmen on a chessboard.

Class Chessman has a field of type BoardField

I want to obtain a list of **positions** of eg. all white Knights on the board.

This code will give me all white knights:

```
    chessmen.stream()
            .filter(chessman -> chessman.getSide().equals(Side.White))
            .filter(chessman -> chessman.getClass().equals(Knight.class))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

What will be the code to obtain only positions of white knights?

The following

```
        chessmen.stream()
            .filter(chessman -> chessman.getSide().equals(Side.White))
            .filter(chessman -> chessman.getClass().equals(Knight.class))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .stream()
            .forEach(chessman -> chessman.getField())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

doesn't work - Compilation error on line`.collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is `Chessman::position` that returns a `BoardField`, it should be as simple as

```
chessmen.stream()
        .filter(chessman -> chessman.getSide().equals(Side.White))
        .filter(chessman -> chessman.getClass().equals(Knight.class))
        .map(Chessman::position)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

which is a short form of

```
chessmen.stream()
        .filter(chessman -> chessman.getSide().equals(Side.White))
        .filter(chessman -> chessman.getClass().equals(Knight.class))
        .map(chessman -> chessman.position())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer just pointing out something wrong I saw in code is you cannot open stream twice. Once you opened stream on any collection and applied the terminal operation it cannot be reused. Terminal operation in this case is `collect and foreach method`

P.S. Still waiting for 50 reputation to add comment so just adding comment in answer section

Comment: Thanks EJ. Yep, I agree, that's right this part of code is mentioned as non-working :)